# Multiple instances of Media Player Classic in multiple windows

Tags: windows-7, video, media-player

How can I set Media Player Classic so that new instances of the player are opened when a new file is opened. Right now, the newly opened video starts playing in the already opened instance.

Answer (score 9):

In the menu go to view->options->player
There's an option to set there to use the same windows or open multiple ones (with a visual representation so it's hard to miss).

I've checked this on MPC-HC 1.4,  but it should be true to other version including the non HC.

[image]